# Ghostscript - PS to PDF - Selecting multiple input files?

Tags: batch-file, pdf, ghostscript, postscript

I created a batch file using the following code to convert PS to PDF, it works well. As an example: The input files have their names set as

> input.ps
>
> input1.ps
>
> input2.ps

etc..

```
gswin64c.exe -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -q -dSAFER -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dPDFSETTINGS=/prepress -sOutputFile="C:\test\bat/output.pdf" input.ps input1.ps input2.ps
```

But my use is that i have the multiple PS files that are present in the path with different filenames(sometimes with random names generated) that i wish to convert to one combined PDF. How can I select an input method in such a way that it selects all the files with ".PS" extension for the process?

Thanks

UPDATE:
Contents of the file.txt:

> XBVC_ABCDEW_L46_ABC2XYZ_SAMPLETEST1.PS XBVC_ABCDEW_L46_ABC2XYZ_SAMPLETEST2.PS XBVC_ABCDEW_L46_ABC2XYZ_SAMPLETEST3.PS XBVC_ABCDEW_L46_ABC2XYZ_SAMPLETEST4.PS

P.S: each filename in the text was continuous with a space between individual file names.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest is by creating a temp file. We clean the file each time we start the script. You can remove `echo` from the last line once you are happy the layout is fine in order to actually run the conversion.

```
@echo off
type nul >file.txt
for %%i in (*.ps) do <nul Set /P "=%%i " >> file.txt
for /f "delims=" %%x in (file.txt) do (
echo gswin64c.exe -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -q -dSAFER -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dPDFSETTINGS=/prepress -sOutputFile="C:\test\bat/output.pdf" %%x
)
```

Comment: Firstly, Thanks a lot!!

Initially, It worked like a charm when I used multiple PS files named as "input". But when I moved some of the typical files to the folder, the batch executes and created the temp file with all the ".PS"file's names in the temp file but no output pdf was created.

Then I redid the steps by only including files named input to test and strangely it din't work now and similar observation as above. I even copied the code you provided and created a new batch and still dint produce a PDF output.

Ex. Typical of File name: "XBVC_ABCDEW_L46_ABC2XYZ_SAMPLETEST1"

Comment: @reddragon please show my the conent of `file.txt` where the output was written to. You can edit your question and add the content.

Comment: please find the contents of the temp file updated in the question.

Comment: @reddragon so some of the `.ps` file names actually have spaces in them?

Comment: Nope. Sorry, that was a test i performed to check if that caused a problem. I re-edited the question now showing the typical temp file contents.  They have a lot of "_", but no spaces.

Comment: @reddragon are the names in new lines each time, or as they displaying in a single line?

Comment: @reddragon as a test, please can you run it manually, take only 2 file names in the string and wrap each with double quotes. i.e `command... "FILE_NAME_1.PS" "FILENAME2.PS"`

Comment: Yes, displays in a single line. As for the test. . did you mean to run like this? ' gswin64c.exe -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -q -dSAFER -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dPDFSETTINGS=/prepress -sOutputFile="C:\Users\cnpanyog\Desktop\bat/output.pdf" "XBVC_ABCDEW_L46_ABC2XYZ_SAMPLETEST4.PS" "XBVC_ABCDEW_L46_ABC2XYZ_SAMPLETEST3.PS" '. This worked in my batch code that i initially made.

Comment: My way of manually typing the inputs into the code worked. But the temp file method din't work.